# How to send real time stream of data from Arduino to a mobile phone via bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, accelerometer

I am doing a project which uses an accelerometer ADXL345 to detect the movement in X,Y,Z axis. And I also use an Arduino Nano. 
Now I got the sketch of Arduino so that I can see the graph in the serial monitor in the Arduino software. 
But once I Tried to connect HM-10 bluetooth with Arduino, the code cannot be uploaded into the software.

Is there anyone can tell me how to code the bluetooth part so that I can send the data in real time to an Android phone. Thank you!

The sketch I have:

```
#include<Wire.h>
#define accel_module (0x53)
byte values[6] ;
char output[512];
void setup(){
Wire.begin();
Serial.begin(9600);
Wire.beginTransmission(accel_module);
Wire.write(0x2D);
Wire.write(0);
Wire.endTransmission();
Wire.beginTransmission(accel_module);
Wire.write(0x2D);
Wire.write(16);
Wire.endTransmission();
Wire.beginTransmission(accel_module);
Wire.write(0x2D);
Wire.write(8);
Wire.endTransmission();
}
void loop(){
int xyzregister = 0x32;
int x, y, z;
Wire.beginTransmission(accel_module);
Wire.write(xyzregister);
Wire.endTransmission();
Wire.beginTransmission(accel_module);
Wire.requestFrom(accel_module, 6);
int i = 0;
while(Wire.available()){
values[i] = Wire.read();
i++;
}
Wire.endTransmission();
x = (((int)values[1]) << 8) | values[0]; 
y = (((int)values[3])<< 8) | values[2]; 
z = (((int)values[5]) << 8) | values[4]; 
sprintf(output, "%d %d %d", x, y, z); 
Serial.print(output); Serial.write(10); 
delay(100); }
```

Answer (score 0):

The TX pin of HM-10 conflicts with the TX signal of the on board usb-to-uart IC. So you cannot upload code when connected HM-10. 
In you case, just connect the Power/RX/GND of HM-10 to arduino Power/TX/GND will be good.